# AWS cognito ResourceNotFoundException: User pool client **** does not exist

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito

I did setup was Cognito pool and app client.

I use the following code to login:

```
import {
  AdminInitiateAuthCommand,
  AdminInitiateAuthCommandInput,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  AdminInitiateAuthRequest,
  AuthFlowType,
  ListUserPoolClientsCommand,
  ListUserPoolClientsRequest,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';
import {
  COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
  COGNITO_REGION,
  COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
  COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET
} from '@/constants';
import crypto from 'crypto';

//@ts-ignore
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') return res.status(405).send();

  const hash = crypto
    .createHmac('SHA256', COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET)
    .update(req.body.username + COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID)
    .digest('base64');

  const params: AdminInitiateAuthRequest = {
    AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
    ClientId: COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    UserPoolId: COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: req.body.username,
      PASSWORD: req.body.password,
      SECRET_HASH: hash,
    },
  };

  const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: COGNITO_REGION,
  });

  const adminInitiateAuthCommand = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand(params);

  try {
    const response = await cognitoClient.send(adminInitiateAuthCommand);
    console.log(response);
    return res.status(response['$metadata'].httpStatusCode).json({
      ...response.AuthenticationResult,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return (
      res
        //@ts-ignore
        .status(err['$metadata'].httpStatusCode)
        //@ts-ignore
        .json({ message: err.toString() })
    );
  }
}
```

and getting exception "ResourceNotFoundException: User pool client **** does not exist." I did check pool client id multiple times. Not sure what can be wrong.

To get ClientId I go to App Integration tab. Scroll down to "App client list" and copy Client Id.

Comment: Are you checking in the right region which is defined in the constants?

Comment: @AnkushJain Yes, I checked also region I set and it's correct one.